# ModuleNotFoundError when executing my setuptools console_script

Tags: python-3.x, path, setuptools

I know many similar questions have been asked, but I feel like I've tried everything and I keep getting the same error. I followed this article https://gehrcke.de/2014/02/distributing-a-python-command-line-application/ and I think I've done the same. Anyway, here's my project structure:

```
nc-textmanager-tool/
├── nc_textmanager
│   ├── gui/
│   ├── textmanager/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __main__.py
│   └── nc_main.py
├── LICENSE
├── bundles.yaml
├── env.yaml
├── requirements.txt
├── README.rst
└── setup.py
```

And here's the content of **setup.py**

```py
import setuptools

with open("README.md", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    long_desc = f.read()

with open("requirements.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    requirements = f.readlines()

setuptools.setup(
    name="nc-textmanager",
    version="1.1.11",
    author="XXX",
    author_email="XXX",
    description="A simple tool for viewing and searching through keys and values used by TextManger in NC projects.",
    long_description=long_desc,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    entry_points={
        "console_scripts": ['nc_textmanager = nc_textmanager.nc_main:run']
    },
    url="???",
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
    python_requires='>=3.8',
    install_requires=requirements
)
```

Installing it by running `python .\setup.py install` works fine, but when I try to run my `nc_textmanager` script from the console, I get this error:

```
> nc_textmanager
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SEHE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\nc_textmanager-script.py", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('nc-textmanager==1.1.11', 'console_scripts', 'nc_textmanager')())
  File "C:\Users\SEHE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\nc_textmanager-script.py", line 25, in importlib_load_entry_point
    return next(matches).load()
  File "C:\Users\SEHE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\metadata.py", line 77, in load
    module = import_module(match.group('module'))
  File "C:\Users\SEHE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nc_textmanager.nc_main'
```

I did try to put the `nc_textmanager-script.py` file in my project root and execute it there, and everything works fine. I'm thus thinking there's an issue with the working directory...

Using python 3.8 on Windows 10.