# console_script not working in editable mode and giving ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, virtualenv, setuptools

I am building a **wheel package** for my project and using `setuptools` for the same, my project **tree** structure is as follows:

> Note : I'm using a **pyenv local** based virtualenvironment named **demo2** with python 3.7.5

```
$tree -L 3
.
├── Makefile
├── README.md
├── feedback_report.csv
├── pyproject.toml
├── setup.py
├── src
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── mypkg
│       ├── QuestionGeneration
│       ├── README.md
│       ├── api
│       ├── data
│       ├── fitb
│       ├── login
│       ├── manage.py
│       ├── poetry.lock
│       ├── pyproject.toml
│       ├── requirements.txt
│       ├── static
│       └── templates
├── test_sample.py
├── tests
│   └── context.py
├── tox.ini
├── zero1.sh
└── zero_out.sh
```

and my `setup.py` file is as follows:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    name='fitbapp',
    version='1.0',
    packages=['mypkg'],
    package_dir = {'mypkg': 'src/mypkg'},
    description='FITB app',
    long_description='App to generate fill in the blanks type questions from sentences',
    classifiers=['Programming Language :: Python'],
    py_modules= ['manage'],
    #install_requires = [ 'docutils', 'numpy' ],
    package_data={'mypkg': ['fitb/*','api/*', 'api/migrations/*.py','static/*.css', 'templates/*.html', 'templates/registration/*.html', 'login/*', 'QuestionGeneration/*', 'fitb/migrations/*.py', 'templatetags/*.py', 'data/pickles/nb-predictor.pkl'] },
    entry_points = {
        'console_scripts' : ['manage-server=mypkg.manage:main'],
    }
    #data_files = [("/", ['static/static.css', 'src/templates/*.html', 'src/templates/registration/login.html'])]

)
```

And my entry_point is specified as **manage-server**, when I execute the build command using the `build` package using - `python -m build` and install the `wheel file` from the **dist** directory, I can access it using `manage-server` with the output as shown below:

```
Type 'manage-server help <subcommand>' for help on a specific subcommand.

Available subcommands:

[auth]
    changepassword
    createsuperuser

[contenttypes]
    remove_stale_contenttypes

[django]
    check
    compilemessages
    createcachetable
    dbshell
    diffsettings
    dumpdata
    flush
    inspectdb
    loaddata
    makemessages
    makemigrations
    migrate
    sendtestemail
    shell
    showmigrations
    sqlflush
    sqlmigrate
    sqlsequencereset
    squashmigrations
    startapp
    startproject
    test
    testserver

[rest_framework]
    generateschema

[sessions]
    clearsessions

[staticfiles]
    collectstatic
    findstatic
    runserver
```

But when I install it in editable mode using:

```
$python install --editable .
```

I get a successful install but the following stacktrace on trying to run `manage-server` (i.e the `manage.py` django file):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/apple/.pyenv/versions/demo2/bin/manage-server", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('fitbapp', 'console_scripts', 'manage-server')())
  File "/Users/apple/.pyenv/versions/demo2/bin/manage-server", line 25, in importlib_load_entry_point
    return next(matches).load()
  File "/Users/apple/.pyenv/versions/3.7.5/envs/demo2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 105, in load
    module = import_module(match.group('module'))
  File "/Users/apple/.pyenv/versions/3.7.5/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mypkg'
```

I don't understand why this is occurring and also it hampers my development in `editable` mode.

My `manage-server` script is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
[ -n "$PYENV_DEBUG" ] && set -x

program="${0##*/}"
if [[ "$program" = "python"* ]]; then
  for arg; do
    case "$arg" in
    -c* | -- ) break ;;
    */* )
      if [ -f "$arg" ]; then
        export PYENV_FILE_ARG="$arg"
        break
      fi
      ;;
    esac
  done
fi

export PYENV_ROOT="/Users/apple/.pyenv"
exec "/Users/apple/.pyenv/libexec/pyenv" exec "$program" "$@"
```

at `/Users/apple/.pyenv/shims/manage-server`, I am on macOS Catalina. I saw a somewhat similar question at [ModuleNotFoundError when executing my setuptools console_script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65704834/modulenotfounderror-when-executing-my-setuptools-console-script), but with no answers and I find that my question is more detailed and different too, due to the use of **editable** mode and use of latest setuptools doc instructions.

I'm opting for a **src/mypkg** layout to add my **template** and **static** files to the *wheel* file converting `mypkg` to a package using `package_data` kwarg of `setup.py`.

> [EDIT] - I tested out whether **console_scripts** do work in a development environment as created by `pip install -e .` and it turns out they do. A Minimal reproducible example is as follows:

[setuptools: entry_points example link](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/entry_point.html)

[entry-points using setup.py file](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html)

The directory structure for this project directory is as follows:

```
$tree

.
├── pyproject.toml
├── setup.py
└── timmins
    ├── __init__.py
    └── __main__.py

1 directory, 4 files
```

The corresponding **pyproject.toml** file is as follows:

```
 [build-system]
 requires = ["setuptools", "wheel"]
 build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

And the corresponding **setup.py** file is as follows:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
     name='testapp',
     version='1.0',
     packages=['timmins'],
     entry_points = {
         'console_scripts': ['hello-world = timmins:hello_world'],
     },




)
```

And on installation of the package using `pip install -e .`, and running `hello-world`, I get the following predicted output:

```
Hello world
```

And hence **console_scripts** should work in the development environment too!

Answer (score 1):

I believe your `package_dir` setting is incorrect which is throwing off the rest of it

It should be

```py
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
```

you also should not have `src/__init__.py`